# Juniper user creation and password

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

I have created the user in Juniper devices by below commands

```
root@qfx5100# set system login user RO class super-user
```

Now the user RO has been created and I have not given any password to it. But when I try to login with RO it asks me for password and when I leave it blank and hit on enter it gives me access denied.

What password should I enter in that case so that I can get access to it.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that will work, Juniper will just refuse the login since there's no valid authentication mechanism configured. The only way to do this properly is by actually setting a password:

```
user@juniper# set system login user teun authentication plain-text-password
```

and/or a SSH key:

```
user@juniper# set system login user teun authentication ssh-rsa "<public key>"
```

Answer (score -3):

```
root@host# edit system login
root@switch# edit user huzeyfe
root@switch# set class super-user
root@switch# set authentication plain-text-password
```